# Validate/Verify social media links

Tags: reactjs, facebook, .net-core, verify, social-media

We're working on a website, that has a feature to create training.
To create a training, a user need to be a instructor and submit his/her facebook, instagram, twitter profile links.
Now we are very curious to know if there's any way to verify the links a user provides (he/she actually own this profile).
I can't find any docs, blogposts about or similar to our requirements.
If there's any way to meet the requirements, any suggestion would be very helpful.
Application backend: ASP.Net Core 6, Frontned: React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook:** Afaik there is no way to verify the user links - The only way to identify a user is by letting him authorize your Facebook App. But the possibility to get his "real" profile URL is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0

**Instagram:** After authorization, you can use this endpoint to get the user/profile name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/

**Twitter:** It should be possible to get the screen_name, so you would just need to match it with the screen_name of the logged in user: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user

In any case, you need different Apps for all platforms. Instagram/Facebook can be one App, but for Twitter you would need a separate one.

Comment: Thank you. So, if we want to verify a user via facebook we need to create a facebook app and then allow user to authenticate/authorize the app from our website?

Comment: @MehediHasanKajol no, that won't help you either. Facebook does not expose the username, or the "real" profile URL via API any more. There is no way to do what you want for Facebook user profiles. (Pages are different.)